# Allow page view only if coming from one other external URL

Tags: url, drupal, weebly

Good morning!
Please help :-)

What:
I want to allow a page to be viewed only if the user is coming from one other external domain page. In other words, you can't see URL "B" unless you came from URL "A."  I don't want them to be able to access the page coming from any other URL or pasting the link in the browser. Both URL A and B are static links.  How can I do that?

Why:
I have a static Weebly "member only" page with a static link to a Drupal site page. If they are a member on my Weebly site, they can see the link and use it. But if someone uses that URL to view the page coming from any other page or just pasting the URL in the browser, I want the page to not display or be redirected back to another static link in my Weebly site. I do not want to have them register as a member on two different sites. I'm keeping the Drupal site for the Views capability to build the page they will view.

Note: I have read that HTTP_REFERER is not a very secure solution. Is that the only option?

Hope this makes sense! Thank you for your expertise and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could include some type of token in your url. Your Drupal URL should look like www.example.com/members?key=fa54sadf551cd8garg5hdasadd2a1d5af.  Every time your page is loaded, you should check the key received via URL matches your stored key for that page.

Then, in your non-Drupal site, you would have to include your key in the URL. This solution would work fine, but somebody could guess your key, and then it would not be private any more.

A more advanced solution would be the following:

1. Set up a web service in your Drupal site, requiring a private key, and offering the dynamic key to enter the member-only page.
2. Use this web service from your non-Drupal site to add this key to the URL displayed to the user
3. Every time the Drupal member-only page is visited, change the dynamic key. This way, next time the non-Drupal page is loaded, the key will be different, and the previous key will not be valid any more.

If your page does not have much traffic, this should work fine. You could change this behaviour to grant user access to those who enter a key that was created in the last 5 minutes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It most certainly does help. I thought about the key idea but as you said, you can see it in the browser. Not so secret ;-)  The web service idea sounds great however. One question, what web service? You mean there is a service provider that does that? How would I implement your advanced solution?  I like it!

Comment: Hi there. Have a look at what is a web service: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service .